# Assigning IAM to API gateway for sdk using cognito federated authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I have setup my Federated Cognito using Facebook to obtain Cognito credentials.  I am looking to protect my API Gateway Resources using the generated SDK for web, IOS, and Android, such that I can deploy my backend via my generated SDK.

If I am using the SDK, do I need to setup a lambda function for Credential checking?
It appears this is not the correct method.

In the SDK Readme, it says:
"#Using AWS IAM for authorization
To initialize the SDK with AWS Credentials use the code below. Note, if you use credentials all requests to the API will be signed. This means you will have to set the appropiate CORS accept-* headers for each request."

However, if I am using the SDK, then why would I be setting any request headers, as this is all baked into the SDK?  What I am missing with this?

Further, if I do set the Cognito credentials when I initiate the sdk, and I set the Authorization setting in the API Gateway to 'IAM', then how do I set a policy to this Resource, such that only my Authorized users of my Federated cognito will be authorized to access my API.

This appears to be a pretty straightforward use-case, and I feel a huge run-around with trying to understand how to configure these basic resources to ensure that ONLY my authorized cognito Role can access the SDK.

Like other AWS resources where you attach an IAM policy directly to the resource, like S3, or Lambda, I expected this would also be the case with the IAM policy for Api Gateway. Instead, I must go write the policy elsewhere.... and which policy is being checked by the API Gateway resoruce, if I set the authorization of that API resource method to IAM...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I finally figured out the steps to make sure to authenticate your SDK for use in the browser, and I am so far assuming this will also apply when you use the SDK in IOS or Android.. I will post again if that isn't the case.

OK. SO the first part that isn't clearly explained when you set up your Cognito Federated accounts, is that in the IAM policy for the unauthenticated role, the default 'Trust Relationship' (this can be accessed from the Role page or your Unauthenticated Role in IAM), doesn't allow for the access to the Facebook authentication, as is expressed in the different writings about setting up Facebook (or other authenticaters) with your Federated Cognito.

So, you need to edit the 'Trust relationship' policy for the Unauthenticated Role:  you need to replace what is currently there for the following section, but, leave the rest of the policy in place:

```
"ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "graph.facebook.com"
        }
```

Your trust relationship should now look like the following:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "YOUR-AUD"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "graph.facebook.com"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Within your API gateway, make sure to set all the resources you wish to be accessed by roles to have IAM policy authentication: you do this by selecting the method request window for your desired method.  Under authorization settings, you set the Authorization to AWS_IAM, and save it.

Because you have the IAM authorization set up on your method, you also must ensure that CORS is setup for that resource.  Select the 'Actions' pulldown menu, and select the option for enabling CORS.  Within this window, simply select the method you need CORS applied to (based upon which methods you have set to have IAM authorization).

Once this is complete, you can deploy your API, and choose your desired SDK.
Now, you must set the correct credentials to your method, so that your SDK object can sign your requests with the correct credentials.

an example:

```
 var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
                    accessKey: AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId,
                    secretKey: AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey,
                    sessionToken: AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken,
                    region: 'YOUR-REGION' 
                });
```

---

You access these credentials from your login method for Facebook (or whichever OAuth provider you have set for your federated account):

```
   AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                IdentityPoolId: 'your-pool-id',
                Logins: {
                    'graph.facebook.com': response.authResponse.accessToken
                }
            });
```

---

In my case, I used this FB authentication method to access the Facebook token:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
});
```

---

Finally, you must give your Cognito Authenticated role the correct IAM policy to be able to invoke your API through the SDK:  You can customize the following policy how you like to limit the access depth your Authenicated Federated Role has to your API gateway resources/methods:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "execute-api:Invoke"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

once you attach this policy, your SDK will be able to successfully make requests to your API.  If you remove the policy, you won't have access.
Also, if you remove the alterations to the Trust policy (as shown above), you also will not be able to gain Cognito identity credentials, and the object for those credentials will remain undefined.

OK, my first stackoverflow post.  Hope it saves someone else a good chunk of running around on the AWS documentation.

---

Now, if you wish to have fine-grained control over who is accessing a resource (for example a Lambda function you are using to access a backend resource) and want to ensure that you have the right cognito ID info to control how your lambda reacts to who is calling the function, you can pass the cognito credentials you needed to execute the Api Gateway method.
The way you do this is simple, however, the one catch is you must ensure that your Authentication role for your Cognito gives permission for the Lambda function.

1. go to the 'Integration Request' for your method.  Check the box: "Invoke with caller credentials".
2. Make sure your CORS are set, and re-deploy your API and SDK.  Now, you can go to your IAM role for your cognito authenticated user, and add a policy that enables that Role to execute the Lambda function.